# Calling React setState from inside a child function

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-accounts

I have a React component that has a function which calls a Meteor login method inside one of it's functions. If login succeeds, I need to to adjust the components state, but that is failing. I am guessing I need another bind(this) or something somewhere but am not sure where. Or maybe I need to extract the setState out into another function and call it from this one. What the typical/best approach to something like this?

-SomeComponent.jsx

```
handleSubmitLogin(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let email="my@email.com";
  let password='mypassword';
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(error) {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
      this.setState({  //<- ***THIS ERRORS WITH 'Cannot read property setState of undefined'***
        showLogin: false,
      });
    } else {
      console.log("There was an error logging in: "
        + error.reason);
    }
  })
}
```

TIA!

Comment: Use `.bind(this)` on the callback function. `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (error) {}.bind(this));`

Comment: Also, it looks like you're using ES6, so you can just use arrow functions: `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => { ... });`. Arrow functions inherit `this` from their surrounding scope.

Comment: both work and thanks for the fast and helpful responses. Since we're slowly migrating to ES6 we'll use the 2nd one. If one of you wants to post your response as an answer, I'll accept it so you can get the rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using ES6, so you can use arrow functions:

`Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => { ... });`

Arrow functions effectively inherit `this` from their surrounding scope, so `this` will refer to the right thing in your function.

If you're stuck on ES5, you can simply bind the `this` context:

`Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (error) { ... }.bind(this));`